# Making a C++ game engine with Lua

Tags: c++, lua, game-engine

So what I want to do is create a game engine in C++ that can be used in lua. Basically, C++ should handle all the graphics/sound/collision/other core game stuff and lua would be used to add content. Can anybody point me in the right direction for making this kind of engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at Cocos2D-X.  It's a C++ game engine and has Lua support baked in.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the Minetest source. It uses Lua as the "mod" language and C++ / irrlicht as the engine, afaik.   http://minetest.net/

Answer (score 0):

See [LÖVE](https://love2d.org/), an engine for making 2D games in Lua.

Comment: No, I want to use C++ for the engine. I would only use Lua for the light stuff (defining items, etc) and c++ would do the more hardware-intensive stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, looks like I may not have been clear about my origional question. However, I have figured out what I am going to do. I will use SFML to write the engine in C++, then use Lua to use it.

Comment: It would be nice if you could comment in your answer why this is a better option for you than the other two C++-based solutions mentioned ie Minetest and cocos2D-x.

Comment: You're right. Originally I didn't think Cocos2D-x would be a good choice because I thought it was Mac OSX only. I am clearly wrong, and it looks like a good choice!

Answer (score 0):

check this: http://oxygine.org
It is C++ game framework for mobile and PC games

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you to read "Game Coding Complete 4-th edition" as it's most complete book on game architecture that I've ever came across. During the course of this book you'll build quite neat 3D engine (and a simple game based on it) that will have support for physics, networking, AI and it will be using LUA scripts for a lot of stuff. So you'll basically learn the best practices of designing games/engines architectures and with this knowledge you'll be in a great place to make your engine (one that you'll build during the course of reading this book) more LUA-driven.

There is only one possible drawback - there is some heavy OOP going on in that book, so, if you are not entirely familiar with the object oriented approach, it could be quite hard to understand at times. But in the end - it's worth it :)